# Improve contrast and quality of barely visible old text written with diluted ink using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Following is an image of page from old parish records. As you can see, the text is barely visible, this is due to use of ink diluted with little too much water... Still, if you try hard enough, you can actually see the letters. I would like to figure out a way to automatically fix such pages to make the text better visible/readable.

[image]

Now I have tried manually in IrfanView some basic effects, the best I got was using edge detection, but still it was from from readable. Now I am trying opencv in Python and with binary threshold I am achieving some results:

```
img = cv2.imread('parish_page.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('processed.png',img)
```

[image]

However this seems to create lots of noise around, also it kind of destroyed right borders of the page. Is there a way to make it cleaner, and/or perhaps even more readable?

I'll be glad for any tips, thanks in advance.

Comment: @nathancy Very interesting references, I will check them out definitely. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potential approach

- Perform [adaptive histogram equalization (CLAHE)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)
- Apply a sharpen filter using [`cv2.filter2D()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d)
- Adaptive threshold

CLAHE

[image]

Now we apply a sharpen kernel using `cv2.filter2D()`. You could try other [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)).

```
[ 0 -1  0]
[-1  5 -1]
[ 0 -1  0]
```

[image]

Finally we perform adaptive thresholding

[image]

Other potential steps after this could be to perform [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to remove noise and further filter the image but since the particles are so tiny, even a `(3x3)` kernel removes too much detail

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE().apply(image)

sharpen_kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,9,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
sharpen = cv2.filter2D(clahe, -1, sharpen_kernel)

thresh = cv2.threshold(sharpen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cv2.imshow('clahe', clahe)
cv2.imwrite('clahe.png', clahe)
cv2.imshow('sharpen', sharpen)
cv2.imwrite('sharpen.png', sharpen)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

In Imagemagick, you could use local area thresholding. (OpenCV has something similar called adaptive thresholding.)

Input:

[image]

```
convert img.png -negate -lat 20x20+2% -negate result.png
```

[image]

Lower/raise the 2% to get more/less gain.